# Android draw on canvas start and stop

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, move

the following code is what I use to draw freehand on a image

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.Paint.Cap;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView;
import com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.TempDemo;
import com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.sample.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class FreehandView extends SubsamplingScaleImageView implements OnTouchListener {
private PointF vPrevious;
private PointF vStart;
private boolean drawing = false;
public static TextView textViewObj1;
public static TextView textViewObj2;
public static TextView textViewObj3;
public static TextView textViewObj4;
public static TextView textViewObj5;
private int strokeWidth;
private List<PointF> sPoints;
public FreehandView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context, attr);
    initialise();
}
public FreehandView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}
private void initialise() {
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    strokeWidth = (int)(density/60f);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (sPoints != null && !drawing) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    boolean consumed = false;
    int touchCount = event.getPointerCount();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:
            drawing=true;
            initialise();
            vStart = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
            vPrevious = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
            // Abort any current drawing, user is zooming
            vStart = null;
            vPrevious = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawing=true;
            PointF sCurrentF = viewToSourceCoord(event.getX(), event.getY());
            PointF sCurrent = new PointF(sCurrentF.x, sCurrentF.y);
            PointF sStart = vStart == null ? null : new PointF(viewToSourceCoord(vStart).x, viewToSourceCoord(vStart).y);
            if (touchCount == 1 && vStart != null) {
                float vDX = Math.abs(event.getX() - vPrevious.x);
                float vDY = Math.abs(event.getY() - vPrevious.y);
                if (vDX >= strokeWidth * 5 || vDY >= strokeWidth * 5) {
                    if (sPoints == null) {
                        sPoints = new ArrayList<PointF>();
                        sPoints.add(sStart);
                    }
                    sPoints.add(sCurrent);
                    vPrevious.x = event.getX();
                    vPrevious.y = event.getY();
                    drawing = true;
                }
                consumed = true;
                invalidate();
            } else if (touchCount == 1) {
                // Consume all one touch drags to prevent odd panning effects handled by the superclass.
                consumed = true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
     }
    // Use parent to handle pinch and two-finger pan.
    return consumed || super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Don't draw anything before image is ready.
    if (!isImageReady()) {
        return;
    }
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    if (sPoints != null && sPoints.size() >= 2) {
        Path vPath = new Path();
        PointF vPrev = sourceToViewCoord(sPoints.get(0).x, sPoints.get(0).y);
        vPath.moveTo(vPrev.x, vPrev.y);
        for (int i = 1; i < sPoints.size(); i++) {
            PointF vPoint = sourceToViewCoord(sPoints.get(i).x, sPoints.get(i).y);
            vPath.quadTo(vPrev.x, vPrev.y, (vPoint.x + vPrev.x) / 2, (vPoint.y + vPrev.y) / 2);
            vPrev = vPoint;
        }
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth * 2);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPath(vPath, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        canvas.drawPath(vPath, paint);
    }
}
public void reset() {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), TempDemo.text5, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (drawing == false)  
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        drawing=true;
    }
    if (drawing == true)  
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        drawing=false;
    }
    //this.sPoints = null;
    //invalidate();
}
}
```

This draws a continuous line from when I i touch my finger to when i release it
I then press my finger agin and it continuse to draw until i release my finger again

Problem is when I touch my finger on a new place on the image it draws a line from where i stopped the last time

I want to be able to stop the drawing when i release my finger and start drawing again from where I put my finger but NOT draw a line between the old stop and the new start

I think it has something to do with movetto but this is my first app with drawing and all the tutorials i can find just have continuous drawing example

Any ideas?

You help as always is appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You use the list of points you called sPoints as only one line. Instead you could use an array of lines:

```
List<List<PointF>> listOfLines = new ArrayList<List<PointF>>();
```

With MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN you start a new line and with MotionEvent.ACTION_UP you make an end to it. In your OnDraw() you can draw all available lines separately.

Rudolf

Comment: Im Sorry I have tried puuting that in but cant work out how to use it. I preseume in my example the crux is vPath.Quadto where vPrev x&y are the coordinates of where it finshed drawing last time and vPoint x&y are the coords of next point if i change vPrev to the coord of where it was touch that should work but I cant work out which variable is the new start cords. What I basically after is a penup and pen down command at a particular start and stop cord

Comment: Just draw the first line using vPath as you did in your Example above using canvas.drawPath(). Then draw the next line with new Path(). List<List<PointF>> is your collection of lines, List<PointF> is one element of this collection (one line) and PointF is one point of one line.